# How to change the frequency of labeling the x and y axis in matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, axis, xticks

I am trying to plot a circle with a grid being shown. I wrote the following script which gives the below picture. However, the labels on the axes are interfering together. How to make the label appear (..,-10,-5,0,5,10,...) KEEPING the grid as it appears in the below figure?. I want to keep the dimension of the grid cell as 1*1 dimension.

I tried to use plt.locator_params(), but the dimension of the grid cell changed and became bigger.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

R1=28

n=64

t=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)    

x1=R1*np.cos(t)
y1=R1*np.sin(t)

plt.axis("square")

plt.grid(True, which='both', axis='both')

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x1)-2,max(x1)+2, step=1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y1)-2,max(y1)+2, step=1))

#plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=5)
#plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5)

plt.plot(x1,y1)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a matplotlib expert, so there may be a better way to do this, but perhaps like the following:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

ax.plot(x1,y1)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))

ax.grid(True, which='both', axis='both')

plt.show()
```

[image]